# How to get Entity Framework 6 to use SQL STUFF function inside CSDL?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using EF 6.1 and would like to create a custom function in the CSDL section of the EDMX file that can call the STUFF function that is built into SQL 2012.
What I have is very simple. (NOTE: This assumes time is HHMM without the colon)

```
<Function Name="StringToDate" ReturnType="DateTime">
    <Parameter Name="strDate" Type="String" />
    <Parameter Name="strTime" Type="String" />
    <DefiningExpression>
        CAST(CASE WHEN strDate &lt;&gt; '' THEN strDate + ' ' 
            + STUFF(strTime, 3, 0, ':') END AS DateTime)
    </DefiningExpression>
</Function>
```

The above code works if I remove the "STUFF" command but with the "STUFF" command I get "'STUFF' cannot be resolved into a valid type or function."

I can use "Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions.Stuff" in LINQ to Entity just fine but not in the CSDL.

NOTE: I am using the STUFF command to insert a Colon between the 2nd and 3rd character in the time variable.

EDIT: "Work Around"
Here is the work around but I would still like to know how to use STUFF in the CSDL if possible.

```
CAST(CASE WHEN strDate &lt;&gt; '' THEN strDate + ' ' +  SUBSTRING(strTime, 1, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(strTime, 3, 2) END AS DateTime)
```

EDIT:
For now I have posted this as an issue on codeplex. Please vote if you are interested.
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2583

Comment: CSDL is a conceptual model not a storage model (SSDL). Query in CSDL must be a valid Entity SQL while query in SSDL must be a valid SQL for your database. You must either find what is a full name of `Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunction.Stuff` in Entity SQL or (imo better) use a store defined function with a real SQL and map it to function in CSDL.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Thanks for clarifying the CSDL / SSDL differences. I could create a custom function that would call the "STUFF" function and place that function inside the SSDL but I was hoping to use the "STUFF" function inside my custom function that I already have in the CSDL. My example listed above was very bare bone and does not show the full function I have in the CSDL. Functions I have written in CSDL do understand some built in SQL functions and I want it to understand the "STUFF" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions declared in the database provider are normally available under the provider's namespace. So if this was a normal Entity SQL query you should be able to invoke STUFF() adding SqlServer before it, e.g. SqlServer.STUFF(strTime, 3, 0, ':').

However, the Entity SQL in the body of a model-defined functions can only refer to other canonical functions or other model-defined functions, i.e. model-defined functions cannot be made provider specific by referring to provider specific functions.

This is a limitation that was adopted by choice. When your application executes a LINQ query you can execute provider specific functions because your application already depends on a full model with conceptual and store schemas and a mapping specification. Model-defined functions on the other hand are part of the conceptual model, which is supposed to be self-contained: you should be able swap the provider, store schema or mapping specification for different ones without ever rendering the conceptual model invalid. Hence things that are defined in the conceptual model cannot depend on things that are defined elsewhere.

**Workaround:**

I did some experimentation and came up with this naïve way to simulate SQL Server's Stuff() using only canonical functions that should work across providers. You can use something like this from your own model-defined function by specifying the namespace of the conceptual model, e.g. Model1.Stuff(strTime, 3, 0, ':')

```
<Function Name="Stuff" ReturnType="String">
  <Parameter Name="character_expression" Type="String" />
  <Parameter Name="start" Type="Int32" />
  <Parameter Name="length" Type="Int32" />
  <Parameter Name="replaceWith_expression" Type="String" />
  <DefiningExpression>
    Left(character_expression,start-1) 
    + replaceWith_expression 
    + Substring(character_expression, start + length, Length(character_expression))
  </DefiningExpression>
</Function>
```

Comment: It still does not let me call the STUFF command while inside a CSDL function. In LINQ I can already use Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions.Stuff for the MS SQL STUFF command. The nice thing about your function is that it will work across providers.

Comment: I have filled in some details in the third paragraph. Although it should be theoretically possible to remove the limitation, there is a design-related reason the limitation exists.